# Write XML code to XML file in Go

Tags: xml, go

I have a script that print-lines XML code, but I need it to write a new XML file and then write the XML code to the file instead of printing it.

Here is the function that prints the XML code

```
func processTopic(id string, properties map[string][]string) {
    fmt.Printf("<card entity=\"%s\">\n", id)
    fmt.Println("  <facts>")
    for k, v := range properties {
        for _,value := range v {
            fmt.Printf("    <fact property=\"%s\">%s</fact>\n", k, value)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("  </facts>")
    fmt.Println("</card>")
}
```

How can I get it to write an XML file and then write the code to that XML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to bgp's (+1) correct answer; by changing the function to take a io.Writer as argument, you can output your XML to any type of output implementing the [io.Writer](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) interface.

```
func processTopic(w io.Writer, id string, properties map[string][]string) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<card entity=\"%s\">\n", id)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "  <facts>")
    for k, v := range properties {
        for _,value := range v {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "    <fact property=\"%s\">%s</fact>\n", k, value)
        }
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "  </facts>")
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "</card>")
}
```

*Printing to screen (Stdout):*

```
processTopic(os.Stdout, id, properties)
```

*Writing to file (code taken from bgp's answer):*

```
f, err := os.Create("out.xml") // create/truncate the file
if err != nil { panic(err) } // panic if error
defer f.Close() // make sure it gets closed after
processTopic(f, id, properties)
```

Comment: Yup, good point - this is better in terms of separation of concerns.  Generating XML most definitely does not need to be in the same function as outputting it.

Answer (score 19):

While printing your XML may be fine, why not use the `encoding/xml` package?
Have your XML structure in go:

```
type Card struct {
    Entity string `xml:"entity,attr"`
    Facts  Facts
}

type Facts struct {
    Fact []Fact
}

type Fact struct {
    Property string `xml:"property,attr"`
    Value string `xml:",innerxml"`
}
```

Create your data structure like this ([running example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/DvkQ-sBOOg)):

```
card := &Card{
    Entity: "1234id",
    Facts: Facts{[]Fact{
        Fact{Property: "prop1", Value: "val1"},
        Fact{Property: "prop2", Value: "val2"},
    }},
}
```

Now you can encode the structure to XML and write it directly to a `io.Writer`:

```
writer, err := os.Open("/tmp/tmp.xml")

encoder := xml.NewEncoder(writer)
err := encoder.Encode(data)

if err != nil { panic(err) }
```

Comment: +1 because it will also help making sure the string values are properly escaped.

Comment: Also compile time type checking.

Answer (score 4):

Use [os.Create](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Create) to open the file and use [fmt.Fprintf](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf) to write to it.

Example:

```
f, err := os.Create("out.xml") // create/truncate the file
if err != nil { panic(err) } // panic if error
defer f.Close() // make sure it gets closed after

fmt.Fprintf(f, "<card entity=\"%s\">\n", id)
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Supporting nemo's comment on the `encoding/xml`; depending on how you're receiving the `fact` data, if it is received as a `map[string]string` then you can also create a Marshaler and Unmarshaler for the `fact` map. This is slightly more complexcan be helpful if you're dealing with larger sets of data that you're not receiving in an ordered manner (ie. unordered map vs ordered array/slice).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "io"
    "os"
)

type FactMap map[string]string

type factXml struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"fact"`
    Prop string `xml:"property,attr"`
    Value string `xml:",innerxml"`
}

// Marshal the fact map
func (fm FactMap) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    if len(fm) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    err := e.EncodeToken(start)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for k, v := range fm {
        // XML encoding the `fact` XML entry
        e.Encode(factXml{Prop: k, Value: v})
    }

    return e.EncodeToken(start.End())
}

// Unmarshal the fact map
func (fm *FactMap) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    *fm = FactMap{}
    for {
        var f factXml

        err := d.Decode(&f)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        (*fm)[f.Prop] = f.Value
    }
    return nil
}

// Note usage of xml.Name to set the outer XML to `card`, as well as setting Entity as an `entity,attr`
type Card struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"card"`
    Entity int `xml:"entity,attr"`
    Facts FactMap `xml:"facts"`
}

func main() {
    props1 := map[string]string{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}

    // Populate the Card struct and marshal it
    card := Card{Entity: 5, Facts: props1}

    // Append to the file
    var f *os.File

    // Check if thet file exists, err != nil if the file does not exist
    _, err := os.Stat("my.xml")
    if err != nil {
        // if the file doesn't exist, open it with write and create flags
        f, err = os.OpenFile("my.xml", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    } else {
        // if the file does exist, open it with append and write flags
        f, err = os.OpenFile("my.xml", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    }
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    e := xml.NewEncoder(f)

    // Write marshal the card struct to the file
    err = e.Encode(card)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```